# Command to list all customizable color highlights

Tags: syntax-highlighting

A few days ago I found a command that allowed me to view all the syntax colors in a theme. I could then determine what highlight I needed to change in order to customize the theme. Can you help me remember what this command is?

Comment: Most probably `:hi`

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to @klaus for providing me with the answer.

`:hi` allows me to view all the syntax highlighting assignments.

Comment: How do I find out though, which one of the multiple hundreds of entries (in my case at least) is responsible for the color of a specific part of the editor?

Comment: @pfincent I am a bit late, but whenever I want to see what the `Group-Name` is, I use this **Command:** `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")`